# Node.js - using request to send multiple HTTP GET's in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send multiple HTTP requests from my node.js server (using the 'request' package) in a for loop.

The idea is to basically have an array of URLs, send a HTTP get for each one, and store the response in an array called 'responseArray'.

When I try this, I get 'undefined', but I know the requests are working if I log them to the console inside the for loop.

```js
function apiCalls() {

  var URLs = [‘URL1’, ‘URL2’, ‘URL3’];
  var responseArray = []
  for (var i = 0; i < URLs.length; i++) {
    request({
      url: URLs[i],
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'close'
      },
    }, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        responseArray.push(String(response.body));
        console.log(responseArray) // this is showing me all the data in the array correctly
        return responseArray;
      }
    }) //end request function
  } //end for loop
  console.log(responseArray)
} //end apiCalls function
apiCalls()
```

So after looking at a few different solutions here on stack overflow and elsehwere I tried using promises. I've never used them before and based this off the [google example](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)

Promise:

```js
var apiCalls = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var URLs = [‘URL1’, ‘URL2’, ‘URL3’];
  var responseArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < URLs.length; i++) {
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
    request({
      url: URLs[i],
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'close'
      },
    }, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        resolve(responseArray.push(String(response.body))
      }
    }) //end request

  } //end for loop
})

apiCalls.then(function(result) {
  console.log('this is calling the promise')
  console.log(result)
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

I always get an empty array when I try to log the responseArray after the for loop. Alternatively - I get 'undefined' if I try to assign the returned array to a variable like so:

```js
var gimmeAllResponses = apiCalls();
console.log(gimmeAllResponses); //returns 'undefined'
```

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong? how do I updated the 'responseArray' data after the for loop has finished?

Comment: Where are you getting `undefined`? On the console? Is it the `console.log(error)` statement, you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit off, since this requires the alternative package, `request-promise`.

You're resolving many times. Since you're using Node.js, it's very likely that ES6 features are available. Use `Array.prototype.map()` and `Promise.all()`:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var URLs = [‘URL1’, ‘URL2’, ‘URL3’];
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
var responseArray = Promise.all(URLs.map((url) => rp({
  uri: url,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Connection': 'close'
  }
}).then((error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      return String(response.body);
    }
  })));
```